# After finishing the countdown I want to show number of counts in a Text View ,eg: after finishing 1st round Text view should show x1, for 2nd round x2

Tags: java, android, countdown

[enter image description here][1]

***emphasized text***
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNgwZ.png

Comment: Please take the time to read the Stack Overflow help file section on how to ask good questions which will receive good answers and edit your question to provide necessary background information. Simply dumping some error messages is insufficient to determine either cause or solution for your problem. These types of low effort postings seldom meet with success on this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a global var and increment that with every timer reset

Example

```
int timerCounts = 0;

@Override
onCreate....


private void starttimer(){
  ......
  .....
  onFinish(){
    timerCounts++;
    your_text_view_to_show_counts.setText(timerCounts+'X');
  }

}
```